# Logstash does not work with input text file

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I have a issue with this, I need to read a text file with logstash to see after in kibana, when I check this logstash.conf with input stdin works, but when I change stdin for file I can not get to work. This is my logstash.conf:

```
    input {
 
        file {
                type => "log"
                path => "C:\Users\elveg\Desktop\ELK\log.txt"
                start_position => "beginning"
                sincedb_path => "NUL"
                ignore_older => "0"
 
         }       
                
 
        }
filter {
      grok {
        match => { "message" => "%{WORD:texto}" }
      }
      date {
        match => [ "@timestamp" , "dd/MMM/yyyy:HH:mm:ss Z" ]
      }
    }
 
output {
 
               elasticsearch {
                hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
                index => ["example"]
                }
 
        
        stdout {
            codec => rubydebug
                }
}
```

I need help with this please

Comment: Could you please paste the error what is coming in logs ??

Comment: I don't see any error in powershell, Where I can see the logs file for this?

Comment: Try to use forward slashes in your path, ` path => "C:/Users/elveg/Desktop/ELK/log.txt"`.

Comment: It could be something in your path or in sincedb_path. Try to fix sincedb_path to an defined file, and delete this file when you relaunch lagstash to be sure that logsash  forget about parsing the input file.

Answer (score 0):

Try using forward slashes instead of backslashes in the path setting.

Comment: try removing sincedb_path and ignore_older temporarily. Also comment your grok filter and check what is the output. Each line of the text file should come as an event.